# how to set ignore case sensitive in this line?

Tags: android

how to set case sensitive in string contain? this is my code below which compare string how do i set ignore case sencitive in this line?? my application check if string contain"LOGIN" in string recieve how do i add ignorecase sensitive so eighter string contain "login" or  "LOGIN" its start application??

```
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
{

abortBroadcast();
    //---get the SMS message passed in---a
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
    SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
    String str = "";  



    if (bundle != null)
    {



        //---retrieve the SMS message received---
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];            
        for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);                

            String phNum = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();  

            str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
            if (specificPhoneNumber.equals(phNum))


            {
                Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");


                ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();

                String where = "address="+phNum;
                Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, new String[] { "_id",   
     "thread_id"}, where, null,
                                  null);




                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {




                    long thread_id = cursor.getLong(1);
                    where = "thread_id="+thread_id;
                    Uri thread = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
                    context.getContentResolver().delete(thread, where, null);


                }


              if (str.contains("LOGIN"))
                      {

                Intent l = new Intent(context,AgAppMenu.class);



            l.putExtra("msg",str);



                l.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(l);

                      }
```

Comment: use this s.equalsIgnoreCase("login"), where s is a string.

Answer (score 2):

```
String str="LOGIN"
```

`str.toLowerCase` gives "login"

so now all you have to do is check for "login" (Because everything is on lowercase now)

```
if (str.toLowerCase().contains("login")) //This works for "login, Login, LOGIN ..."
```

@karn mentioned `s.equalsIgnoreCase("login")` witch is sleeker if you want equality.

If you do go with `s.equalsIgnoreCase("login")` .

If you want to check whether Login/login is in the string then go with `if (str.toLowerCase().contains("login"))`

Comment: but if string contain "LOGIN" then?

Comment: "LOGIN".toLowerCase()= "login" . So you make everything in lowercase() and check with "login". Even "LoGIn" will work

Comment: how do i set ignore case sensitive??

Comment: toLowerCase() does what you want

Comment: i dnt know  resieve string is Uppercase or LOwer how do i set ignorecase statement??

Comment: i mean eighrt string contain upper case or lower its start aplication

Comment: place that line in your code and and will work. No magic there explained everything in my first comment

Comment: @SmartGuy You seem to be going around in circles here. Experiment with "toLowerCase" and you'll see the logic of it.

Comment: but suppose if string contain mixed  like  Login  then??

Comment: @weakwire If you want to make the effort - and I understand if you don't - please break the statement into pieces and explain what each and every part of it does so that "Smart Guy" actually understands -why- this works.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
if (str.contains("LOGIN")||str.contains("login"))
```

or try:

```
if (str.equalsIgnoreCase("login));
```

Comment: i know this but no other solution exist?

Comment: This is far from case insensitive. toLowerCase is the obvious way to go.

Comment: actully i know the word is exist in string  but dont  but dont know in which format user sent me sms  imworking server site application  so dont know user wirte  LOGIN Login or login

Comment: sorry,i am not here.try str.equalsIgnoreCase("login");